# Detect horizontal resize on a ControlListener

Tags: java, resize, swt

I have a ControlListener for detecting resize events on an swt Control. To circumvent a bug in the horizontal resizing, I want to specifically detect when a horizontal resize has occurred. I can't do a manual checking of the canvas bounds, because of a bug occurring somewhere in the layout where a horizontal shrink affects the height (the cause of this bug seems to be outside of the codebase I have access to). So I want to find a way to determine if the event was specifically a horizontal resize, thus allowing me to manually keep the height consistent.

Is there a way to do this with ControlListener? I've looked around a bit and not found a way thus far. Alternatively, is there another kind of listener that can accomplish this? Or a listener that can detect if the west/east boundary was clicked/dragged? Any input would be appreciated.

Thank you. Let me know if there is any way I can make my question clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You probably know that but... You have a ControlEvent parameter when you receive resize event. In this parameter you have width and height that require painting and you also have the related widget.

Don't you think you can use these informations in order to detect horizontal resize ? (this event might also be affected by the layout bug...)

Can't you try to solve the layout bug ?